# Library to convert between Base64 & hex for c++

Tags: open-source, library, c++

I can find no sample code to convert a Base64 string to a hexadecimal string, both in the most readable format, such as

```
5c2e00405e56439da66a4bd279dbfba2d605d6949142ade664ce0fc4a7ceee
0a9f0c5f5b8a13bfe6431fe48de5b7935b6604946c811e3b836f77c28f059df801
```

and

```
XC4AQF5WQ52makvSedv7otYF1pSRQq3mZM4PxKfO7gqfDF9bihO/5kMf5I3lt5NbZgSUbIEeO4Nvd8KPBZ34AQ==
```

Does such an open source library exist? If so, where?

Comment: You could ask this question on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com)... better chances of getting best answers to your question. That site's all about programming!

Comment: Does [this code](http://www.example-code.com/vcpp/reEncode.asp) help you with the conversion?

Comment: Well, I searched again for "Free libraries" as per your question, and found this library called [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/) ... It supports Base64 and Hex conversion, as listed under features...: `hex, base-32, and base-64 coding/decoding` ... I don't know how it does that, but here's a link to the [reference documentation](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/) available on that website.

Comment: Done! Answer posted with features and links to download and reference...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Crypto++® Library 5.6.2**
>
> Crypto++ Library is a free C++ class library of cryptographic schemes.
>
> Other features include:
>
> - pseudo random number generators (PRNG): ANSI X9.17 appendix C, RandomPool
> - password based key derivation functions: PBKDF1 and PBKDF2 from PKCS #5, PBKDF from PKCS #12 appendix B
> - Shamir's secret sharing scheme and Rabin's information dispersal algorithm (IDA)
> - fast multi-precision integer (bignum) and polynomial operations
> - finite field arithmetics, including GF(p) and GF(2^n)
> - prime number generation and verification
> - useful non-cryptographic algorithms
>
>   - DEFLATE (RFC 1951) compression/decompression with gzip (RFC 1952) and zlib RFC 1950) format support
>   - **hex, base-32, and base-64 coding/decoding**
>   - 32-bit CRC and Adler32 checksum
>       class wrappers for these operating system features (optional):
>   - high resolution timers on Windows, Unix, and Mac OS
>   - Berkeley and Windows style sockets
>   - Windows named pipes
>   - /dev/random, /dev/urandom, /dev/srandom
>   - Microsoft's CryptGenRandom on Windows
> - A high level interface for most of the above, using a filter/pipeline metaphor
> - benchmarks and validation testing
> - x86, x86-64 (x64), MMX, and SSE2 assembly code for the most commonly used lgorithms, with run-time CPU feature detection and code selection
>
>   - supports GCC-style and MSVC-style inline assembly, and MASM for x64
> - certain versions are available in FIPS 140-2 validated form

**Download:**
http://www.cryptopp.com/#download

**Manual:**
http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/

Comment: Wow, really well-written answer!

Comment: @Cincinnatus Very-well copied it seems – follow the link to see the original. // **mk117:** copy-pasted content might cause copyright issues, and thus *in this form* is not very welcome on SE sites. You should always make clear what's a copy and what's your own content. The latter is btw missing in your answer – e.g. personal experience with this product ;)

Comment: @Izzy lol, I went straight to the manual.

Comment: For me, the "Download" button raised an eyebrow. Then I saw e-sushi's edit (credits to him for detecting the copy-pasta), and knew the reason ;)

Answer (score 2):

Not too sure about doing it in C++ but in python it is easy:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import base64
import binascii

def Print64Hex(instring):
    """ Prints a base 64 string as hex."""
    data = base64.standard_b64decode(instring)
    print binascii.hexlify(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    for d in sys.argv[1:]:
        Print64Hex(d)
```

So if you just need a utility to do this get [python](http://www.python.org), it is also reasonably simple to embed python within your C++ program and vice-versa so using python as  a library may be an option for you, see [embedding for python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html#methodtable) or for [python3](https://docs.python.org/3.3/extending/embedding.html) *note that for Python3 you need to change print `binascii.hexlify(data)` to `print(binascii.hexlify(data))`* in the code above.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any 3rd party library if you use **[Qt](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html#fromBase64)**:

```
#include <QByteArray>

...

QByteArray str1 = "5c2e00405e56439da66a4bd279dbfba2d605d6949142...";
QByteArray hex = QByteArray::fromHex(str1);

QByteArray str2 = "XC4AQF5WQ52makvSedv7otYF1pSRQq3mZM4PxKfO7gqfDF9bihO...";
QByteArray base64 = QByteArray::fromBase64(str2);

QByteArray hexStr = str2.toHex();
```

Comment: Just to be sure I’m not mistaking: isn’t Qt – being a framework for C++ and QML – “3rd party” too?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the already mentioned, potential solutions…

> [***libb64: Base64 Encoding/Decoding Routines***](http://libb64.sourceforge.net/)
>
> libb64 is a library of ANSI C routines for fast encoding/decoding data into and from a base64-encoded format. C++ wrappers are included, as well as the source code for standalone encoding and decoding executables.

**License:**
Public Domain.

**Download:**
http://sourceforge.net/projects/libb64/files/latest/download?source=files